# Merge different text files into one Excel file, and delete first column of all but first

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, file-manipulation

I need to merge different text files (.sav files) into one Excel file (output.xls), but starting from the second input file onwards, I want to exclude the first column present in each file.

What I want to obtain is the following (with placeholder data to easily see the rows and columns).

File 1

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
B1 B2 B3 B4
C1 C2 C3 C4
and so on
```

File 2

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4
Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
and so on
```

File output

```
A1 A2 A3 A4 X2 X3 X4
B1 B2 B3 B4 Y2 Y3 Y4
C1 C2 C3 C4 Z2 Z3 Z4
and so on
```

Here is my code.

```
import glob
    
filenames = glob.glob("*.sav")
filenames.sort()
with open('output.txt', 'w') as writer:
    readers = [open(filename) for filename in filenames]
    for lines in zip(*readers):
        print(' '.join([line.strip() for line in lines]), file=writer)
    
    
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('output.txt')
df.to_excel('output.csv', 'DATI', index=False, header=False)
    
import os
os.remove('output.txt')
```

However, this keeps all the columns. How do I omit the ones I don't need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as the following.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


fnames = Path("your-path").glob("*.sav")
first_df, *dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t") for f in fnames] 
dfs = [df.iloc[:, 1:] for df in dfs]  # Drop first column

df = pd.concat([first_df, *dfs], axis=1)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```